# Record what I hear

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio-recording, audacity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I record system sounds (apps) in Audacity?](https://superuser.com/questions/111114/how-can-i-record-system-sounds-apps-in-audacity)

How can I record sound that's playing? (obviously I don't want to hold a microphone to the speaker for quality's sake).

I tried Audacity, but it didn't help me. Solution with other software would be OK

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable "Stereo Mix" to be able to capture your system sound. Then you can use that as an ordinary recording device (like a microphone) with any audio recording software. Audacity should work once you do that. See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/ to get started.

Comment: For me, recording devices doesn't list 'stereo mix' :(